# Retrieve selected text in GeckoWebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, geckofx

I am using GeckoFX with C#.NET. Some text in the page can be selected. This text is composed of one or more DOM elements. I want to retrieve the selected text in the page.

***geckoWebBrowser.Window.Selection*** is an accessor for a GeckoSelection object which contains some informations such as

- ***AnchorOffset***: *offset within the (text) node where the selection begins*,
- ***FocusOffset***: *offset within the (text) node where the selection ends*.

I can't find how to get all the nodes & offset where selection starts and ends, or how can I can get a range of all elements spanned by the selection.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround using JavaScript [window.getSelection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getSelection) function.

**Javascript solution** : `JSresult` contains the selected text.

```
GeckoWebBrowser GBrowser = ....
string JSresult = "";
bool bExec;
using (AutoJSContext JScontext = new AutoJSContext(GBrowser.Window.JSContext)) 
   {
      bExec = JScontext.EvaluateScript("window.getSelection().toString();", (nsISupports)GBrowser.Window.DomWindow, out JSresult);
   }
```

**C# GeckoFx solution** : `SelectedText` contains the selected text.

```
GeckoWebBrowser GBrowser = ....
GeckoRange range = GBrowser.Window.Selection.GetRangeAt(0);
string SelectedText = range.CloneContents().TextContent.Trim();
```